# Tagging & branching at the same commit with Maven Release Plugin

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm using the Maven Release Plugin together with Git for version control. I would like to achieve the following. When I create a release on master, say version 1.5.0, I would like to have both a tag and a new branch - starting at that tag. The branch would be there to release fix-releases (e.g. 1.5.1, 1.5.2, etc.). On the master branch, I'd like to see the version bumped to 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, while on the release branch, I''d like to see 1.5.1-SNAPSHOT.

Depicted graphically:

```
      1.5.0 (tag)
      |
------*---- master (branch) --------
      \
       \--- release-1.5 (branch) ---
```

There's the `release:prepare` goal (which would create the tag for me) and there's the `release:branch` goal (which would create the branch for me). After doing `release:prepare`, I can do `release:perform` and all is well. After doing `release:branch`, I can't do `release:perform`, since `release:branch` doesn't create a release.properties file. Of course I can switch to the freshly created branch and do `release:prepare` there - but in that case the tag is created on the release branch and not on master.

Is there a way to create the tag and the branch point at the same commit?